# Android Studio Displaying Copyright Agreement in all my xml files

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Android Studio suddenly displays this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (C) 2019 The Android Open Source Project
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the L
```

and it causes my project to not be able to build. I tried to create a new project but it was fine.
I cannot recreate my project because I am close to finishing it. I cant afford to remake all of the modules. Anybody already experienced this?

Comment: if you are importing it from github or other sources, the license was added in from original source, still i don't understand why your project cannot be built. Or may be you have added a license by yourself.

Comment: Kindly edit question and add build error you are getting

Answer (score 1):

What you are showing are comment lines and have nothing to do with build process.

These kind of copyright is shown if you are using sample projects or cloning from git repository which has added these licences. Sometimes new files may also include this kind of licence - e.g. if you have checked javadoc enabled.

Things you can do

1. Clean project by going to build -> clean project. Then rebuild it.
2. If it doesn't work, share the logs - also you will find appropriate links in the error messages and build logs that indicate what the problem might be and how to fix that.

Note :- In the code you shared, i dont see the comment ending - try adding " **-->** " when comment is supported to end.

Answer (score 0):

delete gradle,idea file,cashes finally Restart your studio.again same issue happening reset your studio.